# Help to understand "be interpreted as also including hostility ... " in the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> A Marxist sociologist has argued that racism stems from the class struggle that is unique to the capitalist system -- that racial prejudice is generated by capitalists as a means of controlling workers.  His thesis works relatively well when applied to discrimination against Blacks in the United States, but his definition of racial prejudice as "racially-based negative prejudgements against a group generally accepted as a race in any given region of ethnic competition," can ***be interpreted as also including hostility toward such ethnic groups as the Chinese in California and the Jews in medieval Europe***.

I have a hard time understanding the second sentence especially the part in bold.  As I read, it should be:

> be interpreted / as also / including hostility toward such ethnic groups / as the Chinese in California and the Jews in medieval Europe.

But I'm not sure.  Can anyone help to spell it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be interpreted as including (can be understood to include) a certain kind of hostility. What kind of hostility? Hostility toward certain ethnic groups. What kind of ethnic groups? Ethnic groups *such as*: Chinese people in California, and Jews in medieval Europe.